# Gaussian quadratic equation

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

For Gaussian (quadratic) form

$$\Delta^2 = ({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu})^T{\bf \Sigma}^{-1}({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu}) \qquad{}$$

where this equation mean and come from?
and what is $$\Delta^2$$ mean in the equation?

After this they resolve the equation like this.

$$-\dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu})^T\Sigma^{-1}({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu})=\\
-\dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}_a-{\pmb \mu}_a)^T\Lambda_{aa}({\bf x}_a-{\pmb \mu}_a) - \dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}_a-{\pmb \mu}_a)^T\Lambda_{ab}({\bf x}_b-{\pmb \mu}_b)\\
-\dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}_b-{\pmb \mu}_b)^T\Lambda_{ba}({\bf x}_a-{\pmb \mu}_a) - \dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}_b-{\pmb \mu}_b)^T\Lambda_{bb}({\bf x}_b-{\pmb \mu}_b) \qquad{}$$
can you explain how this equation derived?

and Also How covariance form calculated in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

The pdf (probability density function) of a normally distributed univariate variable $x$ given $\mu$ (mean) and $\sigma$ (standard deviation) is given by: $f(x|\mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

Let us focus on the part in the exponent: $-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ and extend this to the multivariate case with matrix notation. $(x-\mu)^2$ will become $(\bf x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)$ (note that $\bf x$ and $\mu$ are now column vectors, in your case with element $\bf x_a, x_b$ and $\mu_a, \mu_b)$. $\frac{1}{\sigma}$will become $\Sigma^{-1}$ (with elements $\Lambda_{aa}, \Lambda_{ab}, \Lambda_{ba}, \Lambda_{bb}$ in your case). If we combine these elements, we get your expression for $\Delta^2$.

So to answer your questions:

$\Delta^2$ is the term in the exponent of the pdf of the (multivariate) normal distribution. Note that a normal distribution is a Gaussian distribution.

How the equation $-\dfrac{1}{2}({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu})^T\Sigma^{-1}({\bf x}-{\pmb \mu})$ is derived: Write this expression as vectors/matrices with the elements as I have described above and apply basic matrix algebra (substraction and matrix multiplication is all you need).

Comment: One question how $$\frac{1}{\sigma} become   \Sigma^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: $\Sigma$ (equivalent of $\sigma$) will be the matrix with elements $\sigma_a$, $\rho_{ab}$, $\rho_{ba}$, $\sigma_b$ ($\rho_{ab}$ is the correlation between variable a and b, note that $\rho_{ab} = \rho_{ba}$). Then we take the inverse to obtain $\Sigma^{-1}$ (equivalent of $\frac{1}{\sigma}$) with the $\Lambda$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

You first equation you have given  is simply a *definition* for the quantity $\Delta$, which is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ from the mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ under the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$.  For any argument value $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the probability density of the [multivariate Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) is:

$$\text{N}(\mathbf{x}| \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^n |\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|} \cdot \exp \Big( -\frac{\Delta^2}{2} \Big).$$

In the second equation you give, it appears that the squared Mahalanobis distance is being decomposed into parts, by decomposing the vector $\mathbf{x}$ into two parts $\mathbf{x}_a$ and $\mathbf{x}_b$ with corresponding parts for the mean vector and covariance matrix.  This is a standard decomposition that acts as follows.  Define the [precision matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)) as the inverse of the covariance matrix and decompose it as follows:

$$\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{aa} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ab} \\
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ba} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{bb} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Some simple matrix algebra then gives the decomposition:

$$\begin{aligned}
\Delta^2 
&= (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) \\[6pt]
&= \begin{bmatrix}
(\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a)^\text{T} & (\mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b)^\text{T}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{aa} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ab} \\
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ba} & \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{bb} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a \\ \mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
&= (\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a)^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{aa} (\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a) + (\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a)^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ab} (\mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b) \\[6pt]
&\quad + (\mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b)^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{ba} (\mathbf{x}_a - \boldsymbol{\mu}_a) + (\mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b)^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{bb} (\mathbf{x}_b - \boldsymbol{\mu}_b). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$